# In what context will resumable functions execute in C++14?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future, c++14

One of the proposals for C++14 is [Resumable Functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3564.pdf) which gives C++ what is available in C# today with the async/await mechanisms. The basic idea is that a function can be paused
while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete. When the asynchronous operation completes the function can be resumed where it was paused. This is done in a non-blocking way so that the thread from which the resumable function was invoked will not be blocked.

It is not obvious to me in which context (thread) the function will be resumed. Will it be resumed by the thread from which the function was paused (this is how it is done in C# as I understand it) or does it use another thread?

If it is resumed by the thread from which it was paused, does the thread has to be put in some special state or will the scheduler handle this?

Comment: I have no idea about what you asked about, but if the resume function is non-blocking, then presumably it returns some kind of `std::optional` and the receiver has to check whether the result was available or not. It sounds like you can already code like that with the current mechanics of `std::future`...?

Comment: I don't think that proposal got adopted.

Comment: @Karrek SB: The proposal is linked if you want to read about it. You are right that futures can be used to achieve the same thing (typically with the also proposed future.then). The proposal details how it differs from using futures directly and why this would be a good idea.

Comment: Does not section *3.2 Implementation: Heap-allocated activation frames* provide some information you are looking for? It starts from - "...this design has the advantage of being fairly simple and also 
similar to the implementation that C# relies on for its support of asynchronous methods."

Comment: N3564 doesn't address any scheduling; it just leaves it up to the future implementation (the key section is 3.2.6). Presumably, if N3564 was to be seriously adopted, they would add some kind of `ConfigureAwait` function to specify which Executor the future would use.

Comment: @chris: It was not discussed in Bristol by either CWG or EWG. What practically means it's out of C++14, but will be processed for C++17.

Answer (score 4):

To quote from N3564:

> After suspending, a resumable function may be resumed by the scheduling logic of the runtime and will eventually complete its logic, at which point it executes a return statement (explicit or implicit) and sets the function’s result value in the placeholder.
>
> It should thus be noted that there is an asymmetry between the function’s observed behavior from the outside (caller) and the inside: the outside perspective is that function returns a value of type future at the first suspension point, while the inside perspective is that the function returns a value of type T via a return statement, functions returning future/shared_future behaving somewhat different still.
>
> A resumable function may continue execution on another thread after resuming following a suspension of its execution.

This essentially means that

- When first called, a resumable function executes in the thread context of its caller.
- After each suspension point, the implementation can freely choose on which thread to continue the execution of a resumable function
- From the perspective of the calling code, a resumable function works like an asynchronous function, where part of the (observable) behaviour is reliably executed by the time the function call returns, but the final result might not be in yet (the returned `future<T>` does not have to be in a ready state).
- As a programmer, you don't have to jump through hoops to get a resumable function to resume.

Comment: See some of it in action here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx

Comment: and more here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/resumable-functions-in-c.aspx